# Google App Engine Wildcard Subdomains

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, cloudflare, wildcard-subdomain

I have Node JS app running on google app engine.

I have linked a custom domain to it: www.singlelisting.co

BUT

I need wildcard subdomains to also link to the node application

For Example:  6.singlelisting.co   or ns324.singlelisting.co

I have not had much luck reading the documentation on google developers site 
I am using cloudflare for DNS management and have added * records for all the google A and AAAA records. I believe the problem is have google is seeing the subdomains.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

1. [Mapping subdomains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#using_subdomains): in your [App Engine Custom domains config](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains) you need to add the following entry `*.singlelisting.co` and then update the DSN management with the required records (as you probably did). This means that requests through `6.singlelisting.co` or `ns324.singlelisting.co` will be handled by the `6`, respectively `ns324` service of you App Engine deployment, if available. As the documentation states:

   > If you set up a wildcard subdomain mapping for your custom domain, then your application serves requests for any subdomain that matches:
   >   .If the user browses a domain that matches a service name, the application serves that service.
2. By using [a dispatch file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-requests-are-routed#creating_a_dispatch_file) (more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/dispatchref)): this file will override the [routing rules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_via_url) established (or not) through your domains config.

So basically if you do not have services named `6` and `ns324` that will automatically handle requests incoming through the wildcard rule `*.singlelisting.co`, you have to describe the routing using the `dispatch.yaml`.