# Use wildcard subdomains for Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to set up a wildcard domain on Google Cloud Functions. I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49344836/google-app-engine-wildcard-subdomains) that it's doable for Google App Engine. But how to do it for Google Cloud Functions?

Let's say the wildcard is `*.singlelisting.co`. I would like to reach a function named `bigben` from any of these subdomains `6.singlelisting.co` or `ns324.singlelisting.co`.

So a user would reach `bigben` by visiting `https://6.singlelisting.co/bigben` or `https://ns324.singlelisting.co/bigben`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to get a custom domain for Cloud Functions is through [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).

Firebase Hosting does [not support wildcard domain mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579293/firebase-hosting-can-i-use-a-wildcard-subdomain-with-my-custom-domain), due to its reliance on letsencrypt.org for SSL certificates.